# What is the Doc's middle name?

Tags: back-to-the-future

As you can see in the image of the time train below, there are three letters: "ELB".  Now, it stands to reason that these are probably Doc Brown's initials i.e. **E**mmett **B**rown.  This indicates, though, that Doc has a middle name starting with 'L'.  **What is Doc's middle name?**

[image: Time Train]

Comment: The train is not the only place his middle name initial is mentioned. In the cave where he hid the DeLorean he had carved his initials ELB into a plank of wood. The letter Doc sent to Marty was signed *Your friend in time, "Doc" Emmett L. Brown* - just to name a few examples.

Comment: @larsebert this letter: http://www.bttfstore.com/bttf3_letter_from_doc3.jpg

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Lathrop

The [Back to the Future Wiki page on Doc](http://backtothefuture.wikia.com/wiki/Emmett_Brown) cites the episode *[Put on Your Thinking Caps, Kids! It's Time for Mr. Wisdom!](http://backtothefuture.wikia.com/wiki/Put_on_Your_Thinking_Caps,_Kids!_It%27s_Time_for_Mr._Wisdom!)* as saying the following:

> In the episode, Mr. Wisdom refers to "Emmett Lathrop Brown". Marty
>   replies "Lathrop? So that's what the "L" stands for!"

Answer (score 5):

if you are interested in the middle name I thought you'd be also interested to [know that](https://nationalpost.com/arts/this-is-heavy-doc-25-facts-about-the-back-to-the-future-trilogy):

> The character name of Doc, Emmett Lathrop Brown, contains some secret clues. Emmett is a phoenetic representation of “time” spelled backwards, and Lathrop, is, basically, portal in reverse.